# Keep-alive within python-requests module

Tags: python, http, python-requests, keep-alive

I've got a question about python-requests module. According to the docs

> thanks to urllib3, keep-alive is 100% automatic within a session! Any requests that you make within a session will automatically reuse the appropriate connection!

My sample code looks like this:

```
def make_double_get_request():
    response = requests.get(url=API_URL, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    print response.text
    response = requests.get(url=API_URL, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    print response.text
```

But the log I receive tells that with every request new HTTP connection is starting:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): url
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET url HTTP/1.1" 200 None
response text goes here
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): url
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET url HTTP/1.1" 200 None
response text goes here
```

Am I doing something wrong? By looking at the packets with wireshark it seems that they in fact have keep-alive set.

Comment: how u create these logs?

Comment: @kankan256 The easiest way would be to turn on debug logging, e.g. import logging;
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`Session()` instance](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
def make_double_get_request():
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(url=API_URL, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    print response.text
    response = session.get(url=API_URL, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    print response.text
```

The `requests` top-level HTTP method functions are a convenience API that creates a new `Session` object each time, preventing reuse of connections.

From the documentation:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use `urllib3`'s connection pooling.